# What does if x: mean in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have the following code segment in python

```
if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:  
    recv_data = sock.recv(1024)  
    if recv_data:
        data.outb += recv_data
    else:
        print(f"Closing connection to {data.addr}")
```

Would I read this as: 'if mask and selectos.EVENT_READ are equivalent:'
And similarly: 'if recv_data is equivalent to true:'

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All values have an inherent Boolean value. For the `bytes` value returned by `sock.recv`, the empty value `b''` is false and all other values are true. This is a short, idiomatic way of writing

```
if recv_data != b'':
    ...
```

The `&` is a bitwise AND operator. The result of `mask & selectors.EVENT_READ` produces a value where a bit is 1 if both `mask` and `selectors.EVENT_READ` have a 1, and 0 otherwise. The result of that is an integer which may or may not be 0 (and for `int` values, 0 is false and all others are true).

Basically, `mask & selectors.EVENT_READ` is true if and only if any of the bits set in `selectors.EVENT_READ` are also set in `mask`.

Comment: Not all but any.

Comment: (I meant that last paragraph)

Answer (score 1):

For the second assumptions, yes.

`if var_name:` is shorthand of saying if var_name evaluates to a truthy value.

Your first assumption is wrong though, a logical AND operation in python is actually `and`, not `&` - many languages do use an ampersand as a logical and, but this is usually a double ampersand, as in `&&`. A single ampersand is usually a bitwise AND, not a logical AND.

So in your code above, the first if statement is doing a bitwise (binary) AND on the selectors.READ_EVENT with a bitmask of mask. Basically its a way of asking if the values match, in a binary way. So if READ_EVENT is 010 and the mask is also 010, then the logic evaluates to true. Otherwise